# create a button to create a new opportunity from a task

Tags: custom-button, tasks

I have created a task related to a custom object record which in turn is related to an account record. How would I create a button that would create/launch a new opportunity of a specific record type or failing that take me to the select opportunity record type page while holding onto the account id.

Answer (score 2):

Try just put there

'/006/e?accid={!Something.AccountId}&RecordType={SomeRecordTypeId}'

It will take you to new record on opportunity.
Of course you have to put some record Type Id there

Comment: thanks, why have you "!Something"? where do I put this specifically?

Comment: Because I don't know your object name, you just have to put there Id of parent account, either from relation or formula field